# What's the equivalent but more idiomatic to eval( ) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What's the equivalent to making this call `eval('('+responseText+')')` in jQuery?  I also understand that `eval` is not that safe, so I'm looking for something safer and more idiomatic in jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

Are you actually looking to execute Javascript code (which will always be unsafe to some extent), or are you trying to parse [JSON](http://json.org) from a string into an object?

If the former, eval() is still going to be your best bet.

If the latter, jQuery will [do it for you](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) as part of an AJAX request, or you can use a dedicated [JSON plug-in](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to convert between string and object without the risk of executing arbitrary code.

Answer (score 4):

a) To load and execute JS code:

```
$.getScript( url, [ success(data, textStatus) ] )
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

b) To parse JSON:

```
$.parseJSON( json )
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's true that there are no browser differences.  I just ran across one today.  If you eval a string that calls a method on an object that doesn't exist, Firefox returns undefined and IE6 throws a TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

By design jQuery sets out to improve browser implementations.  Since there aren't problems with the way different browsers implement `eval` it is not addressed by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

`$.globalEval()`?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/

Documentation says that it behaves quite differently than `eval()`, but its the closest match if you want to pass your *evals* via jQuery.