# Is there an equivalent of eval() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, eval

I am trying to create dynamic variables in jQuery. I tried using `eval()` and it seems to work fine but I don't think `eval()` is a jQuery function. Is there an equilvant of `eval()` in jQuery? See my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3CXgy/

```
var test = function(pos) {
    alert(eval('COUNT_'+pos));
}

var COUNT_LEFT = 20;
var COUNT_RIGHT = 30;
test('LEFT');
test('RIGHT');
```

Is there a different way to do this other than using `eval()`? I am not sure if `eval()` is perfectly fine in my example above.

Comment: `eval()` is a Javascript built-in function. jQuery is a Javascript library, so it can use that function. It also provides [$.globalEval()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) which behaves a little differently.

Comment: Check  this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592392/whats-the-equivalent-but-more-idiomatic-to-eval-in-jquery

Comment: Please post your code *here*, with an optional link to a live demo elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are very rarely any reasons to use eval

Here is your code assuming the vars were defined in the head

```
var test = function(pos) {
    alert(window['COUNT_'+pos]);
}

var COUNT_LEFT = 20;
var COUNT_RIGHT = 30;
test('LEFT');
test('RIGHT');
```

To not pollute the global namespace, use

```
var COUNT = {"left":20, "right":30 }
var pos = "left";
alert(COUNT[pos]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally prefer to just store it in an object which we can easily access, add to, modify, and remove from anytime.

```
var count = {
    'left' : 20,
    'right' : 30
}

var test = function(pos){
    alert(count[pos]);
}

test('left');
test('right');
```

If you feel the need to use uppercase, just ensure you use a cohesive pattern, so switch it all to lowercase in the function.

```
var test = function(pos){
    alert(count[pos.toLowerCase()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access a global variable by its name, use this notation :

```
window['COUNT_'+pos]
```

Usually you'd want to have your variable held in an object :

```
var obj = {
     COUNT_LEFT:20,
     COUNT_RIGHT:30
}
```

and then you may access the "variables" as `obj['COUNT_'+pos]`.

Your question as it is written lets think you don't really see what's jQuery. jQuery is a library providing useful functions that you use from your JavaScript code. You can't program in jQuery : you program in JavaScript using JavaScript functions, some of them being taken in the jQuery library.

Comment: almost same thought although I prefer direct access to "base"+var